# Jsonrpc Server instance method "user_account_create" not seen

Tags: python, json-rpc

I have a source file with following code which uses jsonrpclib module of python

```
server = jsonrpclib.Server(url)

try:
  res = server.user_account_create(
    EmailAddress=self.Email,
    FirstName=self.FirstName,
    LastName=self.LastName,
    Password=self.Password
  )
  self.UserId = res['UserId']
except jsonrpclib.jsonrpc.ProtocolError:
  er = json.loads(jsonrpclib.history.response)
  jsonrpclib.history.clear()
  return False
```

But when I looked through the source of jsonrpclib I haven't seen the function `user_account_create`.

Can somebody point what I missed ?

I want to check whether this function makes request to the relative url **/accounts** because that is what explained in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_account_create` should be defined in the server side.

[`jsonrpclib.Server`'s `__getattr__`](https://github.com/joshmarshall/jsonrpclib/blob/b59217c971603a30648b041c84f85159afb2ec31/jsonrpclib/jsonrpc.py#L262) will handle it: `user_account_create` is not defined in the `jsonrpclib.Server`; which cause the `__getattr__` to be called; `xmlrpclib._Method` which represent rpc method is created dynamically.

Comment: So, can I  hope that it will make actually calls   /accounts url ?. Just asking, I will look more about what you mention.

Comment: @SarathBabu, not sure about the actual URL that will be accessed. But it will access the server anyway.